# HTTP on localhost not working with DNS A-record and port forward (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

Tags: port-forwarding, dns-hosting

I have a Jenkins server on my local machine that I publish to the outside world through a DNS A record (ci.alanif.se:8080) with my ISP and port forwarding through two routers.

This works perfectly fine from the outside and from any machine on my local network *except* my local machine, where a browser typically says:

```
Server did not send any data (ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)
```

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try to purge your browsers cache, cookies etc...

Comment: No different. Also happens independent of browser, even if I download another, completely virgin, browser. This is most definitely *not* a browser problem.